# Spark at the Probe's ground lead

Tags: ground, probe

In my set up I have a scope (high end Agilent scope), a PC with a USB port and Device Under Test. The DUT is powered from the USB port of the PC. PC and Scope is connected to the same power strip.

When DUT is powered and when I touch the ground pin of the DUT with the ground lead of the probe, I often see a small spark which means I have a potential difference between the probe's gnd lead and the GND of the DUT.

Is this common? I am surprised to see a potential difference between grounds given all powered from the same power strip. I cannot trust my measurements. What I am doing wrong? Why there is a potential difference between grounds?

Comment: did you measure continuity between usb metal casing and the PSU ground input? maybe they're not connected.

Comment: Measure the AC voltage between PC ground, Scope ground and mains ground, using a multimeter. Your PC earth is probably floating, so you'll see half of the supply voltage from case to ground. Probably caused by a bad multiplug/socket adapter. Many a project has been destroyed by this sort of problem.

Comment: @tomnexus thanks very much. it was a faulty power cable powering the scope. \

Comment: @tomnexus if you be kind enough to put an answer, I like to upvote and accept as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measure the AC voltage between PC ground, Scope ground and mains ground, using a multimeter.

Your PC or scope is probably floating, due to not being earthed properly to the mains, so you'll see half of the supply voltage from case to ground. This is inevitable, if there's no earth, stray capacitance and the EMC filter capacitors are equal between each line and earth. The maximum current is probably only a few mA, by law, but it hurts and it damages electronics.

Many a project has been destroyed by this sort of problem. I once saw it happen to a million dollar antenna's output amplifier, because of one cheap power plug adapter. So keep a bench ground cable and clip everything to it, before connecting up.

Answer (score 1):

A likely culprit for this sparking is the EMI filter in the PC or oscilloscope. This filter is generally located directly behind the mains inlet at the backplate of the PC or instrument. This EMI filter leaks a bit of the AC line voltage to the earth, as it it designed that way.

If both the earth of the PC and instrument are properly connected via the power strip, the problem shouldn't occur.

As Tomnexus already pointed out, check if the earth connections are proper.